# Why does my csv download button only work Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, download, safari

I am working on a project where I have to download a csv file when a button is clicked. Apparently the download works for **Chrome** only. Please help me figure out what I should do to my code to make the download work on all browsers (e.g on Edge, Firefox, Safari...)

Also note that on Safari instead of downloading, it opens the csv file in a new tab.

Here is my code:

```
function download(csv) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    element.target = '_blank';
    element.download = 'services.csv';
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: regarding the new tab issue you set the target to `_blank` which is the parameter used to open as a new tab. but it looks like you’re not specifying a url anywhere, only a file name .. note you pass in a `csv` parameter but are not referencing it anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a 3rd party library for something like this instead of rebuilding the wheel. [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) is a really great cross platform library for problems like this. To get your code working with this library you'd probably do something like this:

```
download(your_csv_data, "services.csv", "text/csv");
```

Check the link for docs and more cool examples.

Comment: i am retting all the results in a single row. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Create markup that looks like the example below.  Use the "download" attribute.

```
<a href="link/to/your/download/file" download>Download link</a>
```

Target="_blank" will cause the file to open in a new tab before the download begins if you want to add that.

```
<a href="link/to/your/download/file" download="filename">Download link</a>
```

If you set the download attribute equal to a string then the file downloaded will take on that value for a name.